Which is a better routing with less crosstalk for diff pairs for Ethernet 100BaseT
I saw some routing the other day in a design, I'm wondering what would be better for less crosstalk. Version 1 has better matching but the diff pairs are closer to each other. Version 2 has better separation but less length matching.
Routing version 1:

Routing version 2:


As non-EE but a sysadmin who has seen various RJ45 jack crimping crimes that still resulted in reliably working 100M and even 1G links, I'm tempted to say that a few mm of unmatched pair lengths won't make a difference whatsoever.

@grawity That's neat, but it will not help the device pass official Ethernet and EMC compliance tests even if it is still capable of forming a link. Compare that with say illegal poor mains wiring inside your walls that still manage to power your sockets just fine, until something happens and starts a fire or electrocutes someone.

@Justme Okay, I'll keep in mind for future that Ethernet or EMC non-compliance can kill people.

@grawity That's not what I meant. Even if it forms a link, you cannot sell it as an Ethernet or EMC  compliant device if it isn't Ethernet or EMC conpliant.

@grawity crosstalk is an issue and PCB traces are much closer than inside wiring or connectors. Attention to detail prevents packet loss.

Version 2 should be better for less crosstalk because there is more separation between pairs.
If the intra-pair length mismatch is minimal and withing suggested range of many appnotes then it's not an issue. 50  mils should be good for even gigabit and  some appnotes allow 600 mils difference.
But as we see only a few millimeters of the MDI wiring and focus on that scope, as a whole it might be irrelevant how you route these few millimeters. There are other items affecting the signal quality too, such as impedance matching, having a ground plane for the signals or not, are ground planes removed under component pads,  is signal via differetial geometry drawn matching the impedance etc.
100BaseTX may be quite forgiving, but it's the whole path that counts, such as minimizing the number of vias.
